# Unbind the "all selector" in jquery

Tags: jquery, selector, bind, unbind

how can i unbind only the "all selector"?

I try `$("*").unbind();` but than jquery unbinds my `$('#demo').click(function())};` too.

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="hv_t"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<hr />
<br /><br /><br />

<div id="demo">Demo</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<div id="unbindHover">unbindHover</div>
```

---

**JS**

```
$('#demo').click(function()
{
    alert('click');
});

$('#unbindHover').click(function()
{
    alert('unbind hover');
    $("*").unbind();
});

$("*").hover( function (e) 
{ 
   $('#hv_t').append('+');

}, function ()
{
   $('#hv_t').append('-');             
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/K4zQA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unbind a specific event binding, specify the event and handler in the `unbind` method. The `hover` method is a shortcut for binding the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, so it's those that you need to unbind:

```
$("*").hover(handleEnter, handleLeave);

function handleEnter() {
  $('#hv_t').append('+');
}

function handleLeave() {
  $('#hv_t').append('-');
}

$('#unbindHover').click(function() {
  $("*").unbind('mouseenter', handleEnter).unbind('mouseleave', handleLeave);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this possible with the click too? Like .click(handleClick) ?

Comment: @user2306309: Yes, you would just use code like `$('#someId').unbind('click', handleClick);`.

Answer (score 2):

For removing the element `#demo` from all selector you can use `.not()` selector:

```
$("*").not('#demo').unbind();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K4zQA/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the ':not(...)' selector.

```
$("*:not(#demo)").unbind();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bradhandy/5hgH2/2/)

There is another feature called event namespaces, but this would involve separating your "hover" call into separate bind calls for "mouseenter" and "mouseleave".  The [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) documentation has information on using event namespaces.

Using one of the "not" options seems to be your best bet.